# Usage of dot '.' in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

What exacly is the usage of `.` in Smalltalk? Based on my understanding, it is the separator of different statements, but can be omitted if statement is at the end. Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.` is a statement separator like `;` in `Pascal` (usually used at the end of lines).  The motivation (reason) being that the ordinary sentences in English end with `.`.

The places it must/could be omitted are:

1. Variable definition
2. Comments
3. One statement block or last statement at the block
4. At the end of a method
5. When you define a `#selector` or `#selector: message`

An example method from Smalltalk/X-jv:

```
selectorAsRegistryName: aSelector
    "Splits selector into string words with spaces. 
     For example: itemName becomes 'Item Name'"
    | registryName selectorCollection | 

    registryName := String new.

    selectorCollection := aSelector asCollectionOfSubCollectionsSeparatedByAnyForWhich:[:ch | ch isUppercase ] withSeparatorsIncluded:true.             
    selectorCollection at: 1 put: selectorCollection copy first asUppercaseFirst. "/ first string must be uppercase too

    selectorCollection do: [ :eachString |
        registryName := registryName isEmpty ifTrue: [ eachString ]
                                            ifFalse: [ registryName, Character space, eachString ]   
    ].    

    ^ registryName
```

Comment: I would not compare it to the ; in C because in C it is a statement terminator -- you cannot omit the ; after the last statement in C. But in Pascal/Delphi you can omit the ; at the end.

Comment: @JayK true.  Pascal is closer to the `.` logic.  I'll edit the answer, thank you for improving the answer.

Comment: Coming from C++/Python/JavaScript, I find it hard to remember when to put `.` and when not to. Specifically for your `5. Selector name or message`, could you elaborate more? Also, is there a tool that can inform(or help) you check the syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @laike9m: a selector `selectorAsRegistryName:` a message here `aSelector` (method name and its parameter in other languages).  I would start putting the `.` everywhere where it should be.  You don't need a special tool - your code will be checked if it is correct when you accept your code.  (At workspace where you can play with your code (select it and `Do it`) you will get an error when incorrect).

Comment: Thanks tukan. Actually I know what a selector and message is, but I don't quite understand what you mean by `.` can be omitted in this case. For example, in your code snippet, `String new.` has dot, and it cannot be omitted.

Comment: @laike9m  Ah, I see.  What I meant is right after e.g `#selectorAsRegistryName` or as stated in the example `#selectorAsRegistryName: aSelector`.  (the method name and parameter).  You don't write neither `selectorAsRegistryName.` nor `selectorAsRegistryName: aSelector.`  .  Within the the method it as shown in the example you end a statement.

Comment: I see, so it means "dot can be omitted when you define a message" if I understand correctly.

Comment: @laike9m yes,precisely. I'll edit the answer for better understading.